# T4 generation by detection of class attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-generation, t4

Is it possible to have T4 interrogate a class library looking for a specific attribute declaration on a class and to act on just that class?

Note:  I am looking to generate some javascript automatically, based on information from specific classes in my project.

Comment: Yes, this related thread should give some idea; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197422/get-all-methods-that-are-decorated-with-a-specific-attribute-using-t4-envdte

Comment: Above comment would work with VS installed. I'm not sure if it continue work in build controller where NO VS is installed.